# Django - Saving string field into date field in Postgres

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django-models, file-upload, django-views

I'm implementing a web application in Django which allows users to upload `CSV` and `Excel` files. The files have 4 columns (maybe in the future it would accept different amount of columns) where two of them are dates. each row in the uploaded file is supposed to be inserted into my Postgresql database.

**I have a difficult time doing two things:**

1. Saving each row of the uploaded file inside the DB. The problem stems from the fact that those two date fields are of `DateTimeField` type, whereas the parsed fields from the uploaded files are of `String` type in-default.
2. I want to extend the functionality of this routine to handle `Excel` files as well, but I have no idea how to do it in an elegant manner without probing the extensions, converting from `Excel` to `CSV`, etc. Do you have a way of doing it elegantly?

   ```
   def upload_file(request) -> render:
    template = 'my-app/upload.html'

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['csvfile']:
        csv_file = request.FILES['csvfile']
        decoded_file = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines()
        csv_reader = DictReader(decoded_file, fieldnames=['col1', 'creation_data', 'last_login_date', 'col2'])
        for user in csv_reader:
            # Create an instance of an User model
            new_user = User()
            # TODO - the fields of dates has to be parsed to datetime!

            new_user.__dict__.update(user)
            # Store this user in the database
            new_user.save()

    return render(request, template)
   ```

Comment: [dateutil.parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) is your friend. `parse('03/29/2021 8:01')  datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 29, 8, 1)` Or you can go the longer route and use `datetime.strptime()` [Strptime](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment you can use datetime.strptime() assuming you know the date format beforehand (since if not, it will be a lot harder and dateutil is your friend in this case)

For the second issue you can use the solution described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-excel-to-csv-in-python/)

You will need to check how to get the data to be read by the excel packages and feed it to the package, so you won't need to save the file before using the data inside it